# Going back to fragment recreates and adds to existing dataset

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a Fragment and I create some data inside `onCreate()`. From this fragment I can go to another one by clicking a Button.
The problem starts when I click the back button. What happens then is that it goes again through `onCreate()` and re-creates a new dataset and adds it to the old one. 
The result is that I end up with two datasets instead of one. How can I skip onCreate when I'm coming from back button or is there another way ?

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
//Check if you're in the button pressed-fragment
    if(){
    //You're code here
    }
}
```

This overrides the backButton and you can do what you want - create new fragments or load the from backstack and other stuff. Be careful though, people don't like to not being able to quit the app with back button.